# Rails sorttable.js No route matches [GET] ".../sorttable.js"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've got Rails 5 app, where I'm trying to add ability to sort table via clickable headers. I tried to use `ransack` gem but have some issues described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138379/rails-sorting-table-through-associated-model).As an alternative I found some really nice JS library called `sortable.js` from this site https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ . Followed instructions all I need to do was:

1. copy/paste `sorttable.js` into `app/assets/javascripts/sorttable.js`
2. put `<script src="sorttable.js"></script>` at the top of my `_pending.list.html.erb`
3. add `sortable` class into table class

`_pending.list.html.erb`

```
<main role="main">
  <div class="left-margin-row top-buffer">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <% if pending_caregiver_authorizations.any? %>
        <div class="multi-modal">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered sortable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Patients</th>
                <th>Requested on</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <% pending_caregiver_authorizations.each do |authorization| %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= link_to "#{authorization.registrant.first_name}", registrant_path(authorization.registrant) %></td>
                  <td><%= authorization.created_at.in_time_zone(Time.zone) %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <h5>No pending authorizations</h5>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

With the above code I gets an error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/caregiver_authorizations/sorttable.js"):
```

If I move the `sorttable.js` file to the same folder where partial `_pending.list.html.erb` lives I'll get the same error.

**[Edit]**

`application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.fileDownload
//= require jquery.dataTables.min
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/core
//= require bootstrap-select
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Do you have a `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file? If so, can you show the code inside that file. Most of the time you include other js files in there.

Comment: @Hackman yes I have, question updated.

Comment: This line: `//= require_tree .` will tell the app to include all js files from the folder: `app/assets/javascripts`. So if you put the sortable.js file there and don't add extra script tags into your view the js should be included.

Comment: It won't sort properly if the data comes from associated model but the RoutingError gone at least. Thanks!

Comment: You could also create a simple sorting function in pure JS without going to the DB again.

Comment: I guess I'm too weak dev for that because I've no idea how to do it.